# Get Error "Index out of range" When I frequently push/back viewcontroller in real device - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, nsindexpath

I have a problem about my tableView.
When  I frequently push/back between ChatListViewController and detailViewcontroller, I will crash and get error in ListViewController.
But I don't know where my data make it crash.
I guess Whether I use GCD to make it happen or not?
Have any advice to avoid it?
Thanks.

Crash Log:
    fatal error: Index out of range
    [image: ![enter image description here]
    [image: ![enter image description here]

Model:

```
class ChatroomList:Model {

    var all:[Chatroom] {
    var rooms:[Chatroom] = [Chatroom]()
    self.chatrooms.forEach({ (id,chatroom) in
        if showType.contains(chatroom.type) {
            rooms.append(chatroom)
        }
    })
    return rooms
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
import Alamofire

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {                     

    let chatrooms:ChatroomList = ChatroomList()
    var list:[Chatroom] = [Chatroom]()
    var subscribe:Disposable?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        subscribe = rooms.notifySubject.subscribe({ json in
                self.loadContents()
        })
        self.loadContents()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        subscribe?.dispose()
    }

    func loadContents() {

        var idList:[String] = []

        self.list.removeAll()
        self.list = chatrooms.all

        guard self.list.isEmpty == false else {
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async() {

            self.list = self.list.filter { (chatroom) -> Bool in
                if chatroom.id.isEmpty {
                    return true
                }
                if idList.contains(chatroom.id) {
                    return false
                }
                idList.append(chatroom.id)
                return true
            }   

            self.list.sort(by: { (a,b) in
                if a.message.datetime.isEmpty {
                    return false
                }

            return a.message.datetime > b.message.datetime
        })

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
      }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if list[indexPath.row].type == .city {

        let cell: ChatroomCityTableViewCell = ChatroomCityTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.loadByCityChatroom(chatroom: list[indexPath.row], cityId: list[indexPath.row].cityId)

        return cell
    }else{

        let cell: ChatroomTableViewCell = ChatroomTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.loadByChatroom(chatroom: list[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: post your crash log, and your crash stacktrace

Comment: I don't have much crash log.I update.

Comment: Error occurs in ChatroomListViewController?

Comment: Yap. Like my post code ViewController.

Comment: Can you share your `cellForRow` method in `ChatRoomListViewController`?

Comment: show your crash log

Answer (score 0):

Enable Zombie Objects in your scheme.

Select your Application Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics -> Check Zombie Objects.

Run your app now. This would give you more precise information about your crash.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not help for me.Thanks

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx ok. enabling zombie objects will provide you the crash reason and method where it occured.  You mentioned index out of range, is it happening in cellForRowAt method?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of information on the internet regarding referencing `self` inside a closure and its implications. Without going into that detail, I would simply recommend to use `[weak self]` where ever you are referencing `self` inside a closure. Something like

```
closure { [weak self] _ in
    self?.whatever()
}
```